# A Javascript event listener's anonymous function keeps returning the same value?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

I was writing a code that basically adds event listeners that call a function with the a fragment of their dom object's id, but every time I click an object with the listener It just gives me the same value no matter what object I click. Here's my code:

```
//add events
for (a=0; a<=tab_array.length-3; a++)
{
alert(a);
document.getElementById("mini_"+a).addEventListener("click",function(){open_tab(a)},false); 
}


function open_tab(e)
{
//change across settings ect
alert("tab "+e+" clicked");
}
```

I realize it probably has something to do with pointers and that fact its using an anonymous function instead of directing passing `a`, but I just don't know what to do instead.

Comment: consider ...addEventListener("click", open_tab.bind(null, a)); see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is correct. The behavior you see is because of your scope.

When your link is clicked javascript is passing the current value of `a`.
This value is `tab_array.length-2` instead of the value `a` had during the loop run `0, 1 ...`.

To keep the value of `a` you have to create a new variable in a new scope (closure). E.g. `e`:

```
for (a=0; a<=tab_array.length-3; a++)
{
  function(e){
    document.getElementById("mini_"+e).addEventListener("click",function(){open_tab(e)},false); 
  }(a));
}
```

Another way would be to write a function which returns your handler inside its own scope:

```
//add events
for (a=0; a<=tab_array.length-3; a++)
{
  alert(a);
  document.getElementById("mini_"+a).addEventListener("click", open_tab(a) ,false); 
}

function open_tab(e) {
  return function() {
    //change across settings ect
    alert("tab "+e+" clicked");
  }
}
```

See <kbd>[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2UgCL/)</kbd> or the <kbd>[Closure guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)</kbd>

Comment: This is a great answer for this sort of thing, which is so common.

Answer (score 0):

Both of @jantimon's code samples are fine ways to solve this problem, but I'd like to suggest a third approach. Instead of a self-calling function expression or a function that returns a function, consider an ordinary named function:

```
for( var i = 0;  i <= tab_array.length - 3;  ++i ) {
    setupTab( i );
}

function setupTab( i ) {
    var element = document.getElementById( 'mini_' + i );
    element.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        open_tab( i );
    }); 
}
```

This is essentially the same code as the self-calling function, but with these advantages:

1. Familiarity. It's just an ordinary function call.
2. Shorter and simpler loop body.
3. With the self-calling function, the function parameter and the actual argument passed in are at opposite ends of the function (parameter at the beginning, argument at the end). A separate function avoids that.

These are just minor advantages, to be sure—any of these approaches will do the trick. But I do like the clarity of this method.